# Can expense ratios on investment options in a 401(k) plan contain part of the overall 401(k) plan fees?

Tags: united-states, 401k

My company was recently acquired and the 401(k) plan is being rolled into the acquiring company's plan.  I'm a fan of indexing and was disappointed that the index funds in the new plan have between two to four times the expense ratios than equivalent index funds in the old plan.  The justification given for the higher expense ratios was that the previous plan had apportioned the 401(k) plan fees more heavily towards the non-index investment options and the new plan apportions the plan fees evenly across all the investment options.  Paraphrasing the justification, the index funds would no longer be able to "freeload" on the backs of the other investment options.

So that made me wonder:

**Can expense ratios on investment options in a 401(k) plan contain part of the overall 401(k) plan fees?  Can a plan be setup to shift the costs to a subset of the plan's investment options?**

**Edit:** I've re-written the question to removing the confusion about the type of fees/costs/expenses.

**Update:** I've looked through the plan prospectus and besides listing the expense ratios of each investment options, the only other disclosure of fees was (paraphrased) that plan administration fees could be charged at the end of the year to account holders if the plan sponsor didn't cover all of them and that some of the fees may have been paid through revenue sharing agreements with one or more of the plan's investment options.  Revenue sharing agreements would be reflected in the expense ratio for a fund, right?  So perhaps the justification was that in the old plan the index funds had no revenue sharing agreements (and therefore lower expense ratios) and the new plan's index funds (which are different funds but the same benchmarks) have revenue sharing agreements, and thus higher expense ratios.  Would that make sense?

Comment: That sounds specious to me, though I'm quite far from an expert.  401(K) plans shouldn't cost much to administer, and the two companies I've worked for both seemed to keep that entirely to themselves - fund expense fees were basically equal to or _less_ what Vanguard would charge me as a personal investor.  Is it possible to get a breakout of fees separately - ie, expense ratios, mutual fund fees, and plan fees, as three separate bits (see http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22728/401k-plan-investment-fees-are-they-the-expense-ratios-or-something-else-as-w?rq=1)?

Comment: The fees should be detailed in the fund prospectus.

Comment: @littleadv - if there's overhead from the administrator, won't that be above and beyond fund fees?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer wouldn't that be charged separately?

Comment: @littleadv - I'd think so. Is the company using higher expense funds so the provider *doesn't* charge extra fee? There's a lot we can't answer. Need to talk to HR/ Admin. On reading OP's edit, he suggested this as well.

Comment: No, revenue sharing agreements will _not_ be included in the expense ratio of the fund that is listed in the prospectus of the fund as is distributed to the public. Your _plan_ **might** be using special share classes with a different expense ratio that is _not_ available to the general public, and whose expense ratio will be specified in the special prospectus provided to you by your 401k plan administrator. But then, you are not investing in the same fund as that available to the general public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things being mixed up in the questions being asked.

The **expense ratio** charged by the mutual fund is built into the
NAV per share of the fund, and you do not see the charge explicitly 
mentioned as a deduction 
on your 401k statement (or in the statement received from the mutual
fund in a non-401k situation). The expense ratio *is* listed in the
fund's prospectus, and should also have been made available to you
in the literature about the new 401k plan that your employer is setting up.

**Mutual fund fees** (for things like having a small balance, or for
that matter, sales charges if any of the funds in the 401k are *load*
funds, God forbid) are different. Some load mutual funds *waive* 
the sales charge load for 401k participants, while some may not.
Actually, it all depends on how hard the employer negotiates with
the 401k administration company who handles all the paperwork
and the mutual fund company with which the 401k administration
company negotiates.  (In the 1980s, Fidelity Magellan (3% sales load) was a
hot fund, but my employer managed to get it as an option in our
plan with no sales load: it helped that my employer was large
and could twist arms more easily than a mom-and-pop outfit or
Solo 401k plan could).
A long long time ago in a galaxy
far far away, my first ever IRA contribution of $2000 into a 
no-load mutual fund resulted in a $25 annual maintenance fee,
but the law allowed the payment of this fee separately from
the $2000 if the IRA owner wished to do so. (If not, the $25
would reduce the IRA balance (and no, this did  not count
as a premature distribution from the IRA).

**Plan expenses** are what the 401k administration company
charges the employer for running the plan (and these
expenses are not necessarily peanuts; a 401k plan is
not something that needs just a spreadsheet -- there is lots of
other paperwork that the employee never gets to see). In some cases, the
employer pays the entire expense as a cost of doing business;
in other cases, part is paid by the employer and the rest is
passed on to the employees.  As far as I know, there is no
mechanism for the employee to pay these expenses outside
the 401k plan (that is, these expenses are (visibly)
deducted from
the 401k plan balance).

Finally, with regard to the question asked: how are plan fees
divided among the investment options? I don't believe that
anyone other than the 401k plan administrator or the employer
can answer this. Even if the employer simply adopts one of
the pre-packaged plans
offered by a big 401k administrator (many brokerages and
mutual fund companies offer these), the exact numbers depend
on *which* pre-packaged plan has been chosen. (I do think the
answers the OP has received are rubbish).

Comment: Looks like I conflated some expenses in the question. I'll update it to see if i can't remove the confusion.  Thanks for such a complete answer on 401k-related fees/expenses.

Answer (score 2):

I question the reliability of the information you received.  Of course, it's possible the former 401(k) provider happened to charge lower expense ratios on its index funds than other available funds and lower the new provider's fees.  There are many many many financial institutions and fees are not fixed between them.  I think the information you received is simply an assumptive justification for the difference in fees.